# Recursive iteration through Child entities in entity framework codefirst

Tags: vb.net, ef-code-first

I have created a VB.net WinForms program and a database using EF Codefirst. In one of the tables, "Categories", there is a column named "ParentCategory_CategoryId" which is the parent category of that particular category (nb it can be NULL). This allows me an unlimited amount of nesting for sub-categories. so far, so good (Categories definition below):

```
Public Class Category
    Public Property CategoryId As Integer
    Public Property CategoryName As String

    Public Overridable Property ChildCategories As List(Of Category)
    Public Overridable Property ParentCategory As Category
End Class
```

The problem arises when I try to populate a TreeView control with this data. My intention is to iterate recursively through the categories and add a TreeNode for each category, and add a sub node for each child category. The VB code is as follows:

```
Private Sub Categories_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' Create new data context        
    Dim dc As New MyContext
    ' Call the recursive function once with Parent category as nothing
    LoadNodesOntoTreeview(dc, Nothing, Nothing)

End Sub

Public Sub LoadNodesOntoTreeview(dc As MyContext, Optional ParentCategory As Category = Nothing, Optional ByRef ParentNode As TreeNode = Nothing)
    Try
        For Each c As Category In dc.Categories.Where(Function(x) x.ParentCategory Is ParentCategory).ToList
            Dim n As New TreeNode With {.Text = c.CategoryName}
            LoadNodesOntoTreeview(dc, c, n)
            If ParentNode Is Nothing Then
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(n)
            Else
                ParentNode.Nodes.Add(n)
            End If
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

For the first iteration (ParentCategory = Nothing) this works fine, however the problem occurs when calling

```
LoadNodesOntoTreeview(dc, c, n)
```

within iteslf. I get the error:

```
"Unable to create a constant value of
type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Category_D3161C0FA58DECDDCD3237
36A77B49BF9AC13F6AB1D9C56D7946173054210834'. Only primitive types or
enumeration types are supported in this context."
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Where clause in your query contains an expression that cannot be resolved by Linq to Entities:

```
dc.Categories.Where(Function(x) x.ParentCategory Is ParentCategory)
```

You can avoid this by comparing the keys of the two objects, rather than their types:

```
dc.Categories.Where(Function(x) x.ParentCategory.CategoryId = ParentCategory.CategoryId)
```

Alternatively, you can run this query using Linq to Objects. To do that, you need to retrieve the Categories data as a collection of objects before evaluating the where clause:

```
dc.Categories.ToList().Where(Function(x) x.ParentCategory Is ParentCategory)
```

Clearly this may mean passing a lot more data across the wire, so the first approach is preferable.

Comment: While this identifies the problem, I don't think it is a good solution.  It would be better to compare x.ParentCategory.CategoryId to ParentCategory.Id to keep the comparison in SQL.

Comment: Agreed, it's more efficient to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Entity Frameworks doesn't know how to transfer classes to actual SQL. If you instead use the CategoryId in your where clause it should work. I use C# so hopefully the following makes sense:

```
For Each c As Category In dc.Categories.Where(Function(x) x.ParentCategory.CategoryId = ParentCategory.CategoryId).ToList
```

Comment: You need to use `=` instead of `Is` in the comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, that has sorted the problem, but I have had to seperate the two cases where the category has 1) no parent and 2) a parent (solution below).

I have also moved

```
Dim dc as new myContext
```

inside the recursive function as I was generating an additional error (the data context cannot be re-used until it has been closed - obviously!).

```
Private Sub Categories_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadNodesOntoTreeview()
End Sub

Public Sub LoadNodesOntoTreeview(Optional ParentCategory As Category = Nothing, Optional ByRef ParentNode As TreeNode = Nothing)
    Try
        Dim dc As New MyContext
        If ParentCategory Is Nothing Then
            For Each c As Category In dc.Categories.Where(Function(x) x.ParentCategory Is Nothing)
                Dim n As New TreeNode With {.Text = c.CategoryName}
                LoadNodesOntoTreeview(c, n)
                TreeView1.Nodes.Add(n)
            Next
        Else
            For Each c As Category In dc.Categories.Where(Function(x) x.ParentCategory.CategoryId = ParentCategory.CategoryId).ToList
                Dim n As New TreeNode With {.Text = c.CategoryName}
                LoadNodesOntoTreeview(c, n)
                ParentNode.Nodes.Add(n)
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I know I could pass just the ParentCategoryId into the recursive function rather than the Category object itself.